# Multiple Senders, 1 Secondary Receiver?

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I was wondering if paypals Adaptive API allows a way to have multiple Senders, collecting the money in my applications and forwarding it the entire amount delayed to a second receiver?

Is there an existing Paypal API for this or a way of combining exiting ones from Paypal? Or would you recommend me to go via different API service, not Paypal?

Answer (score 2):

There can only be one sender in an Adaptive Payments API request. 
If more senders are involved, send one chained payments API request (set a primary receiver) per sender.

Bear in mind that you will want to avoid aggregation of funds in your account, so if there's a time limit, make sure to create a preapproval and collect the funds once the time limit has been reached.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/crowdfunding/ provides some good guidelines for Chained / Parallel Payments.